# Cache:clear fails with The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifeCycleCallbacks" ... does not exist

Tags: php, symfony-3.1

I'm trying to do a preview release for my customer.

Everything is working fine on my development host in the preview environment.

I created a tarball excluding the stuff that isn't needed on the live site.

```
tar \
  --create \
  --auto-compress \
  --dereference \
  --exclude=.DS_Store \
  --exclude=.git \
  --exclude=.idea \
  --exclude=.nfs* \
  --exclude=node_modules \
  --exclude=tests \
  --exclude=var/cache/* \
  --exclude=ToDo* \
  --exclude=var/logs/* \
  --exclude=var/sessions/* \
  --exclude=web/tickets/* \
  --file ./preview.tgz
```

I transferred the tarball to the target host and unpacked it.

Then cded into the directory and issued

```
sudo bin/console cache:clear --env=preview
```

Symfony throws the following error:

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
>
> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifeCycleCallbacks" in class Bcs\BcsVmsUserBundle\Entity\VmsUser does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

I have manually deleted the contents of the cache directory and still get this error.

2016-0801-1124: Additional information.

- I re-generated the auto-load files on the target host. No change.
- I verified that the the HasLifeCycleCallbacks class is defined in the autoload files. It's in autoload_static.php and in autoload_classmap.php.
- I verified that the file specified in the auto-load files does, indeed, exist.

Verbose output from `console cache:clear --env=preview`

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifeCycleCallbacks" in class Bcs\BcsVmsUserBundle\Entity\VmsUser does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.


Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:54
 Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException::semanticalError() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php:708
 Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocParser->Annotation() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php:641
 Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocParser->Annotations() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php:334
 Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocParser->parse() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationReader.php:195
 Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader->getClassAnnotations() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/CachedReader.php:83
 Doctrine\Common\Annotations\CachedReader->getClassAnnotations() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php:63
 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->loadMetadataForClass() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php:102
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:151
 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:332
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78
 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:216
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:281
 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:44
 Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory->getRepository() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:698
 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository() at /var/www/wwui/preview/var/cache/preview/appPreviewDebugProjectContainer.php:450
 appPreviewDebugProjectContainer->getBcs_Vmsuser_RepositoryService() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:275
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/wwui/preview/var/cache/preview/appPreviewDebugProjectContainer.php:437
 appPreviewDebugProjectContainer->getBcs_Vmsuser_LoaderService() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:275
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/wwui/preview/var/cache/preview/appPreviewDebugProjectContainer.php:411
 appPreviewDebugProjectContainer->getBcs_Vmsuser_AuthenticatorService() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:275
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/wwui/preview/var/cache/preview/appPreviewDebugProjectContainer.php:4403
 appPreviewDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:275
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/wwui/preview/var/cache/preview/appPreviewDebugProjectContainer.php:2476
 appPreviewDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_AuthorizationCheckerService() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:275
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/wwui/preview/var/cache/preview/appPreviewDebugProjectContainer.php:1103
 appPreviewDebugProjectContainer->getDplhMenuUtilityService() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:275
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/wwui/preview/var/cache/preview/appPreviewDebugProjectContainer.php:1077
 appPreviewDebugProjectContainer->getDplhMenuDebugCommandService() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:275
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:123
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:98
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->all() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:72
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/wwui/preview/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/wwui/preview/bin/console:29
```

Development host:

- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- PHP 7.0.7-4
- Symfony 3.1.2

Target host:

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- PHP 7.0.8-0
- Symfony 3.1.2 (as part of the tarball)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifeCycleCallbacks` should be `@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifecycleCallbacks` (that's a lowercase c in cycle).

I develop on a Mac which has case-insensitive file systems, by default and deploy to Ubuntu.

Many thanks to sfix and trq on the #symfony IRC node for this answer.

Comment: Worth mentioning to say that even if it is HasLifeCycleCallbacks or ManytoMany, it should be exactly the same as the original function name. 

So ManytoMany should be ManyToMany.